# Bootstrap complex form layout for combined vertical/inline fields

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm very new to Bootstrap but growing fast in my skill and also appreciation for it. I have a need to build a fairly complex page that will contain a lot of form elements, including multiple address fill-in components. I've attached here an image of the basic design that I am aiming for, and can't seem to achieve it with the basic form design elements available to me. I feel like my approach is getting "out of control" in the sense that I've got too many nesting levels and not enough understanding of what I'm actually doing. So rather than post the code I've got so far, can anyone give me a simplified example of how my design might be achieved?

[image]

My dotted-line rectangles represent the fact that my page should have a two-column display, with most of the form elements off to the wider RH side. And then, within that column, my form has some additional levels of complexity. There are many additional form elements that I'm not even showing here, and that's my main reason for wanting to design it this way--because I need to save on vertical screen real estate as much as possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post your code on http://www.bootply.com/ so have something to work with?

Comment: Please post the code directly here in the question, and provide a link for reference. Link-only answers can become useless if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for this.

A simple sample from me. Hope this will help you understand the concept.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Left side for labes
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            Right side for forms
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    longer forms
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    shorter forms
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    shorter forms
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    shorter forms
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    shorter forms
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Right panel with instructions
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice sample, I added this to have a better understanding:
`.row { background-color: blue; border: 1px solid red; }`

Answer (score 6):

Certain types of forms are complicated with and without Bootstrap. There is no complete out of the box solution for your form. You would combine Bootstrap with custom CSS and use nesting. The "easiest" way is to do each chunk, indent, comment and so forth. Be very detail oriented.

This is an example of the more annoying section of the form image you have, which is three nested columns inside the second column. I adjust all my forms that are similar to this to use percentage gutters inside the nested .form-group (which acts like a .row) as the 30px gutter for this is too big. Understanding the grid system, not just using it, will help you get more out of Bootstrap.

[image]

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/sejemi

**CSS:**

```
/* ---- text-align right the .control-label until 699px MAX width -----*/
@media (max-width:767px) { 
    .form-custom .control-label { text-align: right }
}

@media (max-width:699px) { 
    .form-custom .control-label {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .form-custom .payment-inputs { width: 100% }
    .form-custom .submit-form { margin-left: 0 }
}


/* ----------- adjusted nested columns grid and gutters ----------- */
.form-custom .form-group [class*="col-"] .form-group [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
.form-custom .form-group [class*="col-"] .form-group {
    margin-left: -1%;
    margin-right: -1%;
}
.form-custom .form-group [class*="col-"] .form-group [class*="col-"]:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 5px }

@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .form-custom .form-group [class*="col-"] .form-group [class*="col-"]:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 0 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-horizontal form-custom">
      <!-- BEGIN form-group line-1 -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Words Go Here</label>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">Line 1</span>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- /.col-sm-8 -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.form-group -->
      <!-- END form-group line-1 -->
      <!-- BEGIN form-group city-state-zip -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
            <div class="form-group">
               <!-- acts as .row -->
               <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">City</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.input-group -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.col-sm-5 (nested) -->
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">State</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.input-group -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.col-sm-3 (nested) -->
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">Zip</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.input-group -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.col-sm-4 (nested) -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.form-group (nested) -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.col-sm-8 .col-sm-offset-4 -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.form-group -->
      <!-- END form-group city-state-zip -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
         </div>
         <!-- /col-sm-offset-4.col-sm-8 -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.form-group -->
   </form>
</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: can this be done by using labels instead of the input-group-addon?  don't want buttons that show the field field.. just a normal label. next to the input field ... inline of course... can't figure out how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

you should look into bootstrap horizontal forms: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

heres a demo of what youre looking for using bootstrap horizontal forms: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/31/ (this demo also shows the responsive capabilities of bootstrap)

essentially, you want to combine bootstraps grid system with bootstraps horizontal forms.

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    Some other Elements and Instruction Goes Here
</div>
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine vertical and inline groups you should try the following hope it helps

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="line1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location Address</label>
                <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Line 1</span>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name='line1'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Line 2</span>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">PO Box</span>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">City</span>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">State</span>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Zip</span>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Here is the second column</div>
</div>
```

You can see the result here http://jsfiddle.net/a2Lech1u/3/