# Bootstrap Inline Form Fields - City, State, Zip inline but with labels and not buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen examples of trying to get inline inputs side by side, but i'm how do i get those inline inputs with the labels to their side rather than the label looking like a button part using the input group addon.

I've followed the [bootstrap vertical inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825134/bootstrap-complex-form-layout-for-combined-vertical-inline-fields) example Christina's response.  But how would you get the Labels themselves on the same row rather than in a button?   So City State Zipcode, but as labels next to input prompts.

When i try to remove the input-group divs and replace the span that include the input-group-addon, with a LABEL element, the label goes Above the input prompts and not to it's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in order to get just Labels that are attached to the input group you can just play with the CSS to get the look needed.  so i changed the CSS to this: (now I used Christina's answer from linked question in my write up to do this and added this css to get what you see below. She does great job in showing how to get buttons next to each other. 
 Note below image uses two sections of col-6 to get the separate columns.)

```
.customLabel {
    height:20px;
    font-weight: bold;        
    text-align: left;        
    background-color: #fff;        
    border:none; 
}

.form-group {        
    margin-bottom: 0px;         
}
```

This gave me the look of a normal label next to the input prompt. 
This was also using

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
```

form class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">City</span>
      <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Enter City Name">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">State</span>
      <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Enter State Name">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Zipcode</span>
      <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Zip Code">
    </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c04wLvn3/3/)

Something like this?

Comment: As the window will be responsive, please expand the output window when you open the fiddle.

Comment: I experimented with form-inline but i have a big form and only some prompts are on one line, like city state zip.   so if i understand bootstrap just a little, i need to use form-horizontal.  but it seems you can't really use labels that 'stick' to the input control.   they keep showing up above the input controls.  I don't want the text of the label in a 'button' look

Comment: Best option to even show the form-input in grids i.e col-*-* in bootstrap. If you break down them into components and try grid for every line that will be fine. Let me know the structure of your form, so I can help you more.